# Wrong registry key being read when searching the registry C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the values on this node in the registry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources

I am trying to do so with the following code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources", false);
string[] dsnNames = key.GetValueNames();
```

However, when i run this code, It does not read from the node i've hardcoded, it reads from Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources. These are the 32 bit system DSN's only btw.

This is driving me crazy. My machine is Windows 10 Pro build 18363.1198 64 bit. The .Net framework is 4.5.2.

Why is my code not reading from the right registry tree node?

Comment: Google WOW6432Node and you'll immediately find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It *is* the right registry tree node.**

[`WOW6432Node` is `SOFTWARE` but for 32-bit applications on a 64-bit platform](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/whats-wow6432node-under-hkeylocalmachinesoftware-registry-subkey):

> When a 32-bit application queries a value under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\<company>\<product>` subkey, the application reads from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\<company>\<product>` subkey.

If you build your application as 64-bit, it'll use the "original" 64-bit registry tree as desired.

If you don't want to do that, then you're getting the correct key already.